# Should the mean of NN's predicted values match the mean of the original values?

Tags: r, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I built a neural network model in R using the Keras' package and for some reason, the mean of the predicted values of the neural network doesn't match the mean of the original values. For every other model I've built, this is never the case. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a possibility?

Comment: (1) By "predicted", do you mean in-sample fits, or predictions on unseen data? (2) What loss are you using (in the NN and in the other models)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm so sorry for the delay, turns out I just made an error and the problem got corrected. Thank you!

Comment: For those of you in the future, restart R and try to run your code again. That's what I did and it worked.